# How can I tell which version of MVC a Web Application\Site is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

As above... How could you find out, given the source code, what version of MVC an application is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the MVC reference in the web application and go to properties, there should be version property of the referenced MVC dll.

Comment: I just inherited an application but my reference to System.Web.Mvc in the application shows version 0.0.0.0 when I go to properties. Is there another way of knowing what version of MVC is being used by an application? The reference shows a small yellow triangular icon with an exclamation point.

Comment: @Ray If you have a small yellow triangle it means the referenced dll can not be found.  Fix that and you should be able to see the version of mvc.

Comment: I am able to delete the reference and add it back on, but when I am presented with a list of System.Web.Mvc assemblies to add, I have two of them on the Add References dialog: 3.0.0.1 and 4.0.0.0. I need to pick the one the application was using but I don't know which one. I have both installed on my machine but how do I know which one was being used by the application?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1639800.aspx/1), you can programmatically get the version of the assembly with the following:

```
typeof (Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```